# Breaking words at the end of line

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

LaTeX tends to break words at the end of the line when that causes better typography. Great. I'd like to have some sort of influence on where the words are broken, though.

For example, LaTeX currently breaks `cryptography` into `cryptog-raphy` when it does not fit, while I would much rather break it into `crypto-graphy`.

I've tried putting an mbox around it (or around both parts of the word) but that just ends up overflowing the hspace.

Is there a way I can put a box around the word but still allow a break at designated points, i.e. after `crypto` and before `graphy`? I'm fine with doing this on a per-word basis manually.

Comment: In the document where you use the word: `cryp\-to\-graphy` or better as a rule in the preamble `\hyphenation{cryp-to-graphy}`

Comment: The Merriam-Webster dictionary says cryp•tog•ra•phy [link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cryptography) If you use American spelling, you should follow Webster for hyphenation.

Comment: @egreg yep but then there is more than one school when it comes down to hyphens

Comment: @egreg This was just an example (and I prefer breaking it after `to`) but I wanted to know the general fix

Comment: @Joost Hyphenation is not a "personal choice": it's a convention that should be followed. Americans hyphenate fo•tog*ra•phy, while Britons prefer fo•to•gra*phy. If you follow British spelling, also do `\usepackage[british]{babel}`

Comment: While a convention, it is not as explicitly defined as I would prefer it to be. Thanks, changing to british did fix most cases I was a bit annoyed by. I guess that's the convention I should adhere to for everything.

Comment: You've come across a well-known aspect of US-English hyphenation rules: Words that end in "ography" (cryptography, photography, etc) are supposed to be hyphenated *between* `g` and `r`, whereas the associated adjectives (cryptographic, photographic, etc) are supposed to be hyphenated *before* the `gr` group. If that's not in conformance with your hyphenation preferences, be sure to load the `babel` package with the appropriate language option. In your case, the `british` option may be appropriate.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Various possibilities:

- use the right kind of hyphenation rules, e.g., in your case it is possibly `\usepackage[british]{babel}` instead of the default hyphenation patterns
- use `\-` inside a word to explicitly denote the allowed places to break, e.g. `cryp\-to\-graphy`
- specify hyphen exceptions via `\hyphenation{cryp-to-graphy}` (normally in the document preamble). If done then the word `cryptography` used in the document will allow hyphenation at the points indicated by the `-`. Note that only the exact form of the word is affected,  if you use different form, eg plural, you need to specify exceptions for each of them

Comment: the exceptions need to be specified outside of the document e.g. directly below the package import. If you try to do that with a single word, it will not be showing up in your compiled version any longer. Rookie *flies away*.

Comment: @mrk I think you misunderstand what \hyphenation does. It specifies an exception and from that point onwards it is used. This means it can be used anywhere in the document, but of course the best place is in the preamble so that it is always applied. But you can  put it into a paragraph around an offending word, because then the word is used as an exception and no longer typeset. But you could say \hyphenation{foo-bar}foobar in the middle of a paragraph and it would work --- not that this is a good idea, exceptions should go best into the preamble.

Comment: I see, I was not precise enough, my point is only wrapping the word \hyphenation{foo-bar} will not make it show, which happened to me. True that you can specify wherever you want to. I think adding your  \hyphenation{foo-bar}foobar example to the answer is a good idea - then all these comments can go for readabilities sake.