# Indenting lists for homework assignments

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm wondering about a pretty simple thing but I can't seem to get it to work. I'd like to `itemize` my homework questions like this:

https://www.math.ubc.ca/~behrend/math422/2019/A3.pdf

However, when I use

```latex
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\end{enumerate}
```

it parses like:
[image]

That is, the text goes right off the page until I press enter and start over on a new line. I don't normally have to do this for LaTeX to correctly margin text, so what am I doing wrong with `\enumerate` and/or `\item`? Or is there a different, easier way to produce this?

Working example that produces this output on the last `\item`:

```latex
\begin{enumerate}
\item[3.]
\begin{enumerate}
\item The labels consists of sequential numbers.
\item The numbers starts at 1 with every call to the enumerate environment.
\item adsfadsfasfadsfsafl;kajsfl;ksafjadls;fkjadsl;fjadsfadsfasfadsfsafl;kajsfl;ksafjadls;fkjadsl;fjadsfadsfasfadsfsafl;kajsfl;ksafjadls;fkjadsl;fjadsfadsfasfadsfsafl;kajsfl;ksafjadls;fkjadsl;fj
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Normally it should not do that. Could you add an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) reproducing the problem?

Comment: @Vincent Hopefully that's a good working example. Please let me know if you need more.

Comment: @Vincent I've tried multiple editors, it seems to be working this way on all of them. Still not sure what I'm doing wrong. Perhaps there's a better way to achieve this without enumerate and `\item`?

Comment: Does it only happen when you type a single very very long word, or also if you write sentences with separate words?

Comment: @Vincent It's just for a single, ridiculously long word actually. I tried it with normal sentences and it seems to work fine. In that case, I guess it really doesn't matter! Sorry about that.

Comment: Is it also doing it, when you actually use words from the English language? \LaTeX should hyphenate those, see also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121832/breaking-words-at-the-end-of-line).

Comment: As far as I can see the problem has nothing to do with LaTeX and is, instead, a feature of your  "ridiculously long word".  If you put the "word" in the third item outside of the `enumerate` environment then you will see that LaTeX is  unable to hyphenate it when it appears in the body of the document. I do not think it reasonable to expect LaTeX to be able to hyphenate garbage words, so I remain unconvinced that there is a problem here. If you have one please post an example of a word that LaTeX hyphenates differently when it appears in and outside of an `enumerate` environment.