# Remove 'Teil' (Part) from \part page

Tags: german

I had some problems with hyphenating German cities/towns, so I added to the preamble:

```
\usepackage[german]{babel}
```

hoping to fix it.  It seems to work pretty good, but now I have 'teil' (part) above the \part name.  How do I remove this?

Comment: It only makes sense to add `\usepackage[german]{babel}` to your document if your whole document is in German. (Note that for post-1996 orthography rules you want `ngerman`, `german` is *alte Rechtschreibung*.) If you only want to hyphenate some city names, an approach with `\-` or `\hyphenation` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121832/35864) might be appropriate. If you want to use `babel` for German words and your main text is not in German, load it as `\usepackage[ngerman, <main language>]{babel}` and use `\foreignlanguage{ngerman}{Hamburg}`.

Comment: Which document class do you employ?

Comment: ok, thank you, that's helpful.  I think I'm going about it incorrectly.  I just have a bunch of words in French, German, and Italian and want them hyphenated so they are not running outside the margins.  Most of them are places or names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you (a) wish to apply `babel`'s `german` (better: `ngerman`!) language option to the entire document, (b) wish to remove the `Teil` prefix from the Roman-numeral part number on the part-only page, and (c) use either one of the standard LaTeX document classes -- `article`, `report`, and `book` -- or a document class that's derived from one of the standard classes, I suggest you insert the following code in the preamble of your document:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}{\partname\nobreakspace\thepart}{\thepart}{}{}
\makeatother
```

This not only removes `\partname` (which evaluates to `Teil`) but also the subsequent nonbreaking space that gets inserted by default.

Please advise if you do *not* use one of the standard document classes.