# text and tables are located outside the paragraph boundary

Tags: tables, text

I put the part "sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split" and it appeared outside the page boundary. The table is bigger than the page boundary as well.

How to make the table and the text be inside the boundary?

[image]

Comment: What is your question? do you wan to know why is this or how to fix this?

Comment: How to fix these issuess

Comment: See my edits, is that what you wan to say?

Comment: The text issue can be fixed using the URL package.  The easiest way to fix the tabular is to replace the column types from c to p{<width>}]  If you don't know what width to use, use tabularx and an [X] column.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Breaking words at the end of line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/121832/5764); [No hyphen for a word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67571/5764)

Comment: Provide your example code you have tried so that others can fix your problem, otherwise they have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

**For fixing the text issue:**

As I got the word familiar related to machine learning I have a suggestion for you to move the word to the next line using `\\`

```
some text \\ sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split
```

Another way is to use

```
sklearn.model\_selection.train\_test\_split}
```

**For fixing the table problem:**

Use fixed length table column by `p{5cm}` (where *5cm* is the length of column) so that you can control the width of the table.

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{5cm} | p{5cm}}
    Column 1 & Column 2\\ \hline
    Column 1 & Column 2\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

If you provide your code/[MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) I can make this more useful.

Comment: Thanks `@VScode_fanboy` for your nice edit.

Comment: Always my duty, as the welcoming and service this site has done for me.

Comment: did you test that `\hyphenation` command?